# Not able to serialize the object when posting the json data

Tags: jquery, json

I am using following jQuery code to post the json data by serializing the 'hospital' Object when I entered details and click on save button, but unable to achieve, since the object is not serializing.Please help me to resolve this error.

```
$("#hospital")
.submit(function() {
    if (jQuery('#hospital').validationEngine('validate')) {
        alert('json submit');                                               
        var hospital = $(this).serializeObject();
        $.postJSON("form",hospital,function(data) {
        window.location = '<c:url value="/hospital/search?sid=" />'
        + data.hospitalId;
        });
        return false;
    } else {
      jQuery('#hospital').validationEngine('validate');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What is the value of `hospital`?  Does `$(this)` select the same element as `$('#hospital')` in your code?

Comment: var hospital = $(this).serialize();

Comment: If you're just going to pass it to a jQuery AJAX function, there's no reason to use `serializeObject`. It's only needed if you want to use the object in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#hospital")
.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    if (jQuery('#hospital').validationEngine('validate')) {
        alert('json submit');                                               
        var hospital = $(this).serialize();
        $.post("form",{hospital : hospital},function(data) {
        window.location.href = '/hospital/search?sid='+ data.hospitalId; // sid? or id?just check
        },'json');
        return false;
    } else {
      jQuery('#hospital').validationEngine('validate');
            }
        });
    });
```

if you read examples in a post method in jquery you will find it helpful and answer you
[jQuery Post Method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Hi Yousef,Thank you so much for your valuable time and answer, unfortunately your code also dint work for me :( After the serialization it was unable to call crl that was specified in the form. And i found the error that was occurring due to following two lines of code.

Comment: Since I was using jQuery datepicker I had <script type="text/javascript"src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"/> these lined in my ui page and I have solved this by using html5 datepicker. But I dint get the exact reason for this problem :(

Comment: I don know whats hospitalId is?.anyway check my updated answer  hope it will help a bit to solve that